# dynamic array element deletion for multiple types

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

```
type TSomething = record
 name: string;
 value: integer;
end;    
type TOtherSomething = record
 data: extended;
 data2: extended;
 data3: array of TSomethingAlien;
end;
...
dynarray1: array of TSomething;
dynarray2: array of TOtherSomething;
```

Also, there's nasty procedure of deleting elements for each type:

```
procedure TForm1.DeleteSomething(N: integer);
begin
   if N > High(dynarray1) then Exit;
   if N < Low(dynarray1) then Exit;
   if N = High(dynarray1) then begin
     SetLength(dynarray1, Length(dynarray1) - 1);
     Exit;
   end;
   Finalize(dynarray1[N]) ;
   System.Move(dynarray1[N +1], dynarray1[N],(Length(dynarray1) - N  -1) * SizeOf(TSomething) + 1) ;
   setLength(dynarray1, Length(dynarray1) - 1) ;
end;                          

procedure TForm1.DeleteOtherSomething(N: integer);
... got the idea?
```

Binding the procedure to global object wasn't smart, but compiler groaned, when a `var Dyna: array of TSomething` was in function arguments, so Dyna was used instead of addressing to dynarray1. So I even can't overload the function for multiple data types with var argument!
 `SetLength(Dyna, length(dynarray1)`
 **type mismatch!**
 `SetLength(Dyna, length(Dyna)`
 **type mismatch!**

What is wanted:

1. *Overloaded* `DeleteElement(var Arr: TMultipleTypes, N: element)`: see above, why can't reach this goal.
2. single `DeleteElement` implementation that works with any type of data in array? Something like <template> type support?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, normal tlist class does most of this stuff, but is based on an array of pointers

The generic "tfplist"  (requires 2.4.0+, see fgl unit) might be closer to what you want. But generics are still beta.